# How to structure a python package made of multiple sub-projects?

Tags: python, package

what is the correct way to structure a python package for multiple functionalities?

I have a case where my project can be broken into 3 completely separate, logical chunks that are entirely decoupled. As such, I have broken the sub-projects into respective folders in my python package project. This has led to a file structure like this;

```
foobartoo
|_setup.py
|_foobartoo
  |_foo
  | |_foo.py
  |
  |_bar
  | |_bar.py
  |
  |_too
    |_too.py
```

This method keeps things together but separate nicely, but after installing I have noticed a definite problem. The only way to access one of the files is to do

```py
from foobartoo.foo.foo import <method/class>
```

or

```py
import foobartoo.foo.foo as <something>
<something>.<method/class>
```

This seems extremely impractical.

I can see two alternatives

1. scrapping the folder system and having foo.py, bar.py and too.py in the same directory under foobartoo.

This seems bad because it will be impossible to know which file/code belongs to which of the projects

2. breaking the single package into multiple packages.

This seems ok, but it would be better if the 3 things were together as they are intended to be used together.

I have looked at numpy and its source code, and somehow they seem to have a lot of their functionality behind many folders, yet they dont need to reference any of the folders. This seems ideal, just being able to do something like

```py
import foobartoo

foobartoo.<classname/methodname>()
```

Comment: Even thought this is very late, the correct method of doing this was to import the classes into the __init__.py at the base level of my package structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional paths to your 'main' script so sys will search automatically to many directories like:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append(example_sub_dir)
import sub_script
sys.path.remove(example_sub_dir)
```

!note that you can add many directories on sys to search but you need to care as import time will be rise respectivelly